# creating edit page for profile in django

Tags: python, django, edit, profile

i am a beginner. my project is regarding the companies and customers. i have created, profile page for them. now i want to create an edit page such that companies can edit their profile. 
my model is:

```
class Company_Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(_('Company Name'), max_length= 30)
    logo = models.FileField(_('Company Logo'), upload_to=get_upload_file_name, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(_('Contact Address'), max_length=50)
    phone_no = models.IntegerField(_('Contact No'), max_length=12) 

class Customer_Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name'), max_length= 30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(_('Middle Name'), max_length= 30,null = True,blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name'), max_length= 30)
    photo = models.ImageField(_('Photo'), upload_to=get_upload_file_name, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(_('Contact Address'), max_length=50)
    phone_no = models.IntegerField(_('Contact No'), max_length=12)
```

my views.py is:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           user = User.objects.create_user(
           username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
           password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
           email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            )
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    catagories = Company_Profile.objects.all()
    customers = Customer_Profile.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index1.html',
                          {'form': form, 'catagories': catagories,     'customers' : customers},RequestContext(request))

def edit_company(request, offset):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       company_edit = update_company_prof(request.POST, instance = request.user.company_profile)
       if company_edit.is_valid():
           company_edit.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('company/'+str(company_edit.id))
    else:
       company_edit = update_company_prof(instance = request.user.company_profile)
    return render_to_response('edit_comp_prof.html', {'company_edit':   company_edit}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my html page for edit is:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{{ company_edit.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Update" />
 <input type="reset" class="btn" value="cancel">
</form>
```

my update_comp_prof form is :

```
class update_company_prof(UpdateView):
    class Meta:
       model = Company_Profile
       fields = ('name','logo','address','phone_no')
```

i am getting only update button nothingelse. help me...

Comment: Please format your code properly, the indentation is all over the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since you have `ForeignKey`s to the `User` model in your profile models, there can be more than one profile per `User`. If you want it to be a single one, change them to:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Then you can access to your profile by using the model name, for example:

```
instance = request.user.company_profile
```

or

```
instance = request.user.user_profile
```

Comment: i changed to OnetoOnefield , and instance = request.user.company_profile  now i am getting only the update button nothing else. i will edit my code

Comment: Can you also post the code for `update_company_prof`

Comment: Your `update_company_prof` must extend `forms.ModelForm`, not `UpdateView`. Also consider changing the name of `update_company_prof` to something like `CompanyProfileForm` as it is very misleading at the moment.

Comment: the logo is appearing as a link. what should i do to make the photo appear.

Comment: You can't fix it within the form but you can put an img tag elsewhere in your template: `<img src="{{ user.company_profile.photo.url }}">`

Answer (score 1):

Your update_company_prof must extend forms.ModelForm, not UpdateView. Also consider changing the name of update_company_prof to something like CompanyProfileForm as it is very misleading at the moment.